# how to set tf for gmapping

Tags: navigation, odometry, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to build a map using gmapping with my robot in Gazebo,and I faced a problem about setting up the right tf so the gmapping can do the right job.

Now I am able to load the urdf file into Gazebo, display it in rviz and observe the data of Laser scans.

But when I use the command **rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping**,it says

**[ WARN] [1455451234.661271473, 384.435000000]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.**

I suppose the tf or the odom is not set propelly,so I tried **rosrun tf view_frames**, and I get

**robot/odom→robot/base_footprint→base_footprint→base_link→hokuyo_link**

I have also checked the tutorials and books,but these mostly use packages like turtlebot etc. in a bag playback mode rather than real-time gmapping and I could not understand how to boardcast the right transform in this case.

Can any one help on this issue? What are the exact things I need to do?
Many thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226582/how-to-set-tf-for-gmapping/) by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Akif implied in his answer, try:

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping _odom_frame:='robot/odom'
```

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on 2016-02-15**:
Thank you very much, I can build the map now! Hoooray!

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-15**:
Cool! Could you please "mark my answer as correct" by clicking on the checkmark on the left?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you check [gmapping wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping), it has lots of parameters. Therefore, if you run it without setting any parameter, it will launch with default parameters.

For example, in your case, default parameter for `odom_frame` is `odom`. So if your odom frame is `robot/odom`, it may not handle transformations right. Therefore you may try using a launch file with correct parameter settings.

You can take a look at [turtlebot repo](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/gmapping.launch.xml) for a sample launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on 2016-02-15**:
Thank you very much, I can build the map now! Hoooray!